# I found a function on DBViewer, but it doesn't present on PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new to PL/SQL and DBView.

I got below log after doing some action on front end application.
When I want to check on PL/SQL function/ procedure/ package, I can't find it using "find database objects" fiture.

> Command : { ? = call ap_val_sb_prod_code (?,?,?,?,?,?)
>
> I/P 1 is : 615
>
> I/P 2 is : 9222
>
> I/O 11 is 0

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say *how* you tried to find it.

Generally speaking, if it is your own schema, you'd query `USER_OBJECTS`, e.g.

```
select * from user_objects where upper(object_name) = 'AP_VAL_SB_PROD_CODE';
```

---

If you have privileges to view other users' objects, then query `ALL_OBJECTS` instead:

```
select * from all_objects where upper(object_name) = 'AP_VAL_SB_PROD_CODE';
```

---

Finally, to check the whole database, query `DBA_OBJECTS` (but you have to have privileges to do that):

```
select * from dba_objects where upper(object_name) = 'AP_VAL_SB_PROD_CODE';
```

Comment: It's really helpful. I got the function on another schema :)))